# Table with out text .Net6 + Knockout.js + DataTables.net

Tags: knockout.js, datatables, .net-6.0

When page load then fill this:

```
 <select class="form-control" 
        data-bind="options: UsersList,
                optionsText: function(item) {
                    return item.name()
                },
                value: selectedUser"></select>
```

then select one of the user and

```
 self.loadADGroups = () => {
        self.selectedUser().ActiveDirectoryUserGroupList.removeAll();
        let getParams = {
            distinguishedName: self.selectedUser().ident()
        };

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: ActiveDirectoryGroupsListUrl,
            data: getParams,
            success: (responseData) => {
                responseData.forEach((o, i, a) => {
                    var vm = getActiveDirectoryGroupViewModel(o);
                    self.selectedUser().ActiveDirectoryUserGroupList.push(vm);
                });
            },
            error: () => {
            }
        });
    }
```

Html table :

```
<div id="ReportActiveDirectoryGroupUser" data-bind="with: selectedUser() ">
    <table id="ReportTableActiveDirectoryGroupUser"  style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nazwa grupy w AD</th>
                <th>Opis grupy w AD</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: ActiveDirectoryUserGroupList">
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text: AdName"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: Addecsription"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

The table has the same number of rows as the model returned from the controller, but there is no data in them and there are in the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return model has `AdName`, `AdDescription`—but in `responsedata`, there was `adName`, `adDescription`.

```
getActiveDirectoryGroupViewModel = (apiResponseObject) => {
    var result = new ActiveDirectoryGroupViewModel();

    result.AdName(apiResponseObject.adName);
    result.Addecsription(apiResponseObject.addecsription);

    return result;
}
```

This work.